# Avoiding 'sort order by' in query plan

Tags: sql, oracle, sorting, optimization, indexing

I have a table like this:

```
create table A (
    fieldA numeric,
    fieldB varchar(255),
    fieldC varchar(255),
... fields ... constraints ... 
);
```

And I have unique B-tree index on `fieldB`. So, when I execute query like this:

```
select /*+ index(a)*/ * from A a where fieldB > 'LOW' and fieldB < 'HIGH' order by fieldB
```

I expect to see query plan with index range scan and without sort order by clause (or any other type of sort), because of existing index. 
In fact, I have `sort order by` in query plan

```
explain plan for select /*+ index(a)*/ * from A a where fieldB > 'LOW' and fieldB < 'HIGH' order by fieldB
```

Result:

```
SELECT STATEMENT                     
SORT ORDER BY                       
TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED
INDEX RANGE SCAN
```

If I remove `order by` in my query, i will not get data in needed order (that is strange for me, because by default B-Tree index should build tree of rows in ascending order and in that case `select * from A` and `select * from A order by fieldB` should give the same query plan as i thought)

How can I avoid `sort order by`?

Oracle version: 12.2

Comment: You have order by clause in your query hence you cannot avoid that. Incase you want to avoid, you need to remove that `Order By` clause from your query,

Comment: @XING , the problem is that i need to guarantee that data will be returned in the particular order. If i remove `order by` i will lose this order. But my goal is to achieve the same logic without `order by` by using B-Tree index ascending ordering wich is the default. But it didn't work for me. So, i don't understand why optimizer choose to sort data agin even if i want to return the data in the same order as index built it

Comment: What happens if you only select fieldB from your query?

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen, hm, i get data in ascending order as i want.  But how can i achieve this selecting not only fieldB, but other fields too without order by?

Comment: Also, if i do `select fieldB from A order by fieldB asc` i get `sort order by` in query plan, but i will get data in the same order as without `order by` and without any sort clause in query plan

Comment: I'm not an oracle expert by far - but I'm not sure you can get what you're trying to achieve, because I suspect that unless you put all the data into the index, you'll still need to sort as you need to look up the data not in index. And even even so - I'm not sure the engine guarantees the order without order by even if the index is sorted "correctly". So depending on what the actual issue is, you might need to look at alternative solutions.

Comment: The reason why i think that it is possible is that when oracle go through the index it gets 2 values - Index value and ROWID. If we have ROWID we can get the needed row without searching it. As we got the rowid using index, we will get all data from DB in the same order. That is my expectations

Comment: But the way it'd get that data by ROWID would _very simplified_  be like joining tables, so it'd need to sort the resulting dataset to guarantee a sort order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in `NLS_LANGUAGE` and `NLS_TERRITORY` parameters of session. 
By default, my session has

`NLS_LANGUAGE= 'RUSSIAN'`

`NLS_TERRITORY= 'RUSSIA'`

And when i try to get the data in particular order using varchar indexing value and order by in query i get additional `sort order by` in query plan.

After I changed these parameters:

`NLS_LANGUAGE= 'AMERICAN'`

`NLS_TERRITORY= 'AMERICA'`

I don't get additional `sort order by` in my query plan.

Now, queries:

`EXPLAIN PLAN FOR select * from SIEBEL_CT.A a where fieldB > 'LOW' and fieldB < 'HIGH' order by fieldB`

`EXPLAIN PLAN FOR select * from SIEBEL_CT.A a where fieldB > 'LOW' and fieldB < 'HIGH'`

Have the same query plan

Comment: Presumably that's stopped the `BATCHED` access too - so is it actually more efficient overall? Has it made any other changes to the plan?

Comment: @AlexPoole , Final result in query plan is: ```SELECT STATEMENT,             
 FILTER         ,             
  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID,
   INDEX RANGE SCAN          
```

i'm not sure will it be more efficient or not (didn't test it yet), but i achieved my first goal - remove sort order by in query plan

Comment: USA USA USA USA

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use `/*+ index(a)*/` hint when you already have the index on your column. Let optimizer choose the best execution plan for your query. See below:

Table:

```
create table A (
    fieldA numeric,
    fieldB varchar(255),
    fieldC varchar(255)
);

create index indx on A(fieldB);
```

Query:

```
select * from A a where fieldB > 'LOW' and fieldB < 'HIGH' order by fieldB ;
```

Plan: Sort by Order is not used.

```
Plan Hash Value  : 4131509220 

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                      | Name | Rows | Bytes | Cost | Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT               |      |    1 |   271 |    0 |          |
| * 1 |   FILTER                       |      |      |       |      |          |
|   2 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID | A    |    1 |   271 |    1 | 00:00:01 |
| * 3 |     INDEX RANGE SCAN           | INDX |    1 |       |    1 | 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
------------------------------------------
* 1 - filter(NULL IS NOT NULL)
* 3 - access("FIELDB">'LOW' AND "FIELDB"<'HIGH')


Note
-----
- dynamic sampling used for this statement
```

Comment: It's strange, but it didn't help. I've just repeated step by step, but in result i got ```SELECT STATEMENT                      |      |
 SORT ORDER BY                        |      |
  FILTER                              |      |
   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED| A    |
    INDEX RANGE SCAN                  | INDX |
```

Comment: I did it like this: ```CREATE TABLE A (
     fieldA numeric,
    fieldB varchar(255),
    fieldC varchar(255)
);

create index indx on A(fieldB);

EXPLAIN PLAN FOR select * from A a where fieldB > 'LOW' and fieldB < 'HIGH' order by fieldB ;
SELECT * FROM TABLE (dbms_xplan.display);```.

Also, i use Datagrip 2017.2.2 + JDBC. Can it be the reason? I'm asking that weird question because if i try the same in the PL/SQL developer tool, i don't get `sort order by` in query plan

Comment: @NickRyan Am using Oracle 11gR2. and the post is based on that. Not sure how its behaving in Oracle 12c. But whats the issue even if plan have sort by order. Optimizer thinks thats the best way , then whats wrong going with that

Comment: The problem is that it adds additional cost even if it isn't necessary to do

Answer (score 1):

The `TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED` access path is new in 12c; [from the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/tgsql/optimizer-access-paths.html#GUID-7953EB83-0BBA-4700-993A-49C9B5FD254A):

> The database uses the rowids obtained from the index to find the corresponding rows from the ... table, and then retrieve them. The `BATCHED` access ... means that the database retrieves a few rowids from the index, and then attempts to access rows in block order to improve the clustering and reduce the number of times that the database must access a block.

It's retrieving the actual data more efficiently by reducing the number of times it hits each block (assuming the actual data distribution means there were blocks with relevant data for more than one row). But as a result the data retrieved is not necessarily in index order, so it needs to be sorted explicitly.

> As we got the rowid using index, we will get all data from DB in the same order. That is my expectations

That isn't true any more with `BATCHED` access.

> The problem is that it adds additional cost even if it isn't necessary to do.

But it is necessary; and you aren't seeing the cost *reduction* from the batched access (which depends on the actual data distribution, as mentioned before). You can't really look at one cost value in isolation. The optimiser usually knows what it's doing. (I don't think the hint is affecting this at all, but I'd agree with @XING that you shouldn't have it - unless you're really sure you know something the optimiser doesn't).

---

It's worth noting that even though the 11g version didn't show an explicit sort (as per @XING's demo), Oracle has never guaranteed the order results will be returned without an `order by` clause, and with a simple `TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID` (i.e. not `BATCHED`) the optimiser is just able to skip the explicit sort because it already knows the data was retrieved in that order. Which is what you alluded to in a comment.

In 11g you'd *probably* get the rows back in the desired order without the `order by` clause but only because of the implementation details of how Oracle is getting the indexed rowid's and then the corresponding data row-by-row. But it isn't guaranteed. This sort of under-the-hood change is exactly why it's always been wise to explicitly `order by` even when it appeared to be redundant. As you are doing in your current code. But it isn't redundant, and never was really.

(There was a similar 'issue' with group-by in an earlier release; it usually implied a sort order (up to 9i I think) and people omitted the `order by`; but then the optimiser changed (I think in 10g) and that caught people out...)